# Removing the array braces and their values from a list of data

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of numbers in the format 555-555-5555, where they were copied from an array in the browser, but the array bracket [ ] values copies with them and i am trying to remove those [0] => but it's not working.

```
$file = file_get_contents('numberlistarray.txt'); // For e.g. [1] => 555-555-5555
preg_match_all('/(.*)[^>]|=>|/si', $file, $m);
preg_replace($m, '', $file);
echo $file;
```

I used the | character because i am receiving preg_replace errors regarding the '=' sign.
Any suggestions?

Comment: its some what difficult , why can't you try to save all the data as strings,, so that its possible to parse data.

Comment: The only reason i approached this method is because my foreach() and file_out_contents/fwrite i tried initially didn't place the phone numbers in the text file....didn't even present an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here try this:

```
"/\=\>\s*([0-9\-]+)/i"
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied from array in the browser means you copied it from javascript? I suggest using the json notation to cleanly import and export objects/arrays/values.
See http://www.json.org/js.html and http://www.php.net/json_decode

To mask a preserved character in Regex you should use \ instead of | (as php masks too, you msut use \).

Comment: I used `$number = serialize($number);
$number = json_encode($number);
$number = json_decode($number);
file_put_contents("phonenumbers.txt", $number);`<though i received the numbers in a strange format now. What am i doing wrong? Was it something i weren't meant to initialize?

Comment: did you read and understand the first link? you get the numbers from your own website? how do you format them?

Comment: The same way i have them in the example if that's what you meant.